# Set locale using locale pragma

Tags: perl, locale

I am trying to override the default locale settings from within a Perl script. First I tried to do the override from Bash shell command line:

**p.pl**

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
my @data = qw( A a B b C c );
{
    use locale;
    say join ', ', sort @data;
}
```

When running this script I can override the current locale from the command line by setting the variable `LC_ALL`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C p.pl
A, B, C, a, b, c
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 p.pl
a, A, b, B, c, C
```

However, if I override from within the Perl script it does not work:

**p2.pl**:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    $ENV{LC_ALL} = "C";
}
my @data = qw( A a B b C c );
{
    use locale;
    say join ', ', sort @data;
}
```

When I run `p2.pl` it does not give me the `LC_ALL=C` sort order:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 p2.pl
a, A, b, B, c, C
```

it still gives me `en_US.UTF-8` sort order. I thought that setting `$ENV{LC_ALL}="C"` should be enough to override the command line ( outside environment settings ). What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using locale module, you can change locale with `setlocale` function. But be aware that it's exported by default and can affect other programs. Don't use this with threads.
For sorting, it's maybe better to use LC_COLLATE, LC_ALL affects all locale settings, which is maybe not desired here.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use POSIX qw(locale_h);
use locale;
my $old_locale = setlocale(LC_COLLATE);

my @data = qw( A a B b C c );
print join ', ', sort @data;
print "\n";

# change current locale
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "C");
print join ', ', sort @data;
print "\n";

# reset back to default
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "");
```

For more information, refer to [setlocale documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#The-setlocale-function).

Further explanation ([source](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130946)):

Because the locale pragma isn't a runtime action, as setlocale() is.
The pragma is a lexically-scoped declaration.  The effect of the pragma
is that, where there are locale-using and locale-ignoring variants of an
operation, the locale-using variant will be used.  The string comparison
that sort uses by default is such an operation.

Where a locale-using operation is invoked, its behaviour is influenced by
the current locale.  That's not a lexically-determined static attribute
of the operation, but a runtime global variable.  This is libc's model
of locale, which Perl is exposing.  The locale is initialised very early
in execution, in the manner recommended by the environment variables.
The libc model is that later changes in the environment variables do
not automatically change one's locale.  The current locale can be set
under program control, to match new environment settings or in a manner
unrelated to the environment, but it never changes without the program's
request.  So you setting the environment variable during program execution
(even in a BEGIN block) doesn't change the current locale.

So you need to do both things to get the locale effect you're looking
for: lexical declaration that you want to use locale-specific sorting,
and runtime action to select the locale that you want.

Comment: Thanks, but why can't I use the `locale` pragma as in my question to do this?

Comment: It's in the documentation. You are not calling `setlocale` function.

From doc (shortened), at least one of the following has to be true:
1. The locale has to be correctly set at the time when application starts either by yourself or whomever set up your system account; or
2. The application must set its own locale using the setlocale() method.

Comment: Maybe, but I am still a little bit confused. It works with `p.pl` (and I am not calling `setlocale()` in `p.pl`).

Comment: Ah ok. By default, Perl ignores current locale settings. With `use locale` pragma, you are telling it to not ignore them.

Comment: To be more precise... `LC_ALL=C p.pl` is like `export LC_ALL=C; p.pl`. You export LC_ALL before running the script (option 1. in my previous comment). With BEGIN section, the script is already running, so 1. is false and you have to use 2. - `setlocale`. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Hmm.. *"The locale has to be correctly set at the time when application starts"* I would interpret that statements as "before `use locale` is encountered within the script", so that is why I tried to put the setting in a `BEGIN {}` block in order to set it up correctly before the application started. But somehow, things seems to be determined even before `use locale` is parsed by Perl :)

Comment: BEGIN {} block is not executed before the start, but at the very beginning; the script is already started when processing BEGIN block.

Comment: Hi David. I got more details about the issue from this question: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130946. Feel free to add details to your answer.